# .NET Library for programming Allan Bradley Logix5000

Tags: .net, dll, plc

I would like to know if there are any available .NET libraries to program Logix5000 software from an external application.

So far I could only find stuff to read/write to the tags of the actual PLC, and to create UDTs.

Our projects use a predefined standard with the routines, and therefore it would save heaps of time if I could write an external application to simply export the routines, or even directly alter the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to work directly with the 5000 software, but you can use .NET to create either a L5K (text) or L5X (XML) file that can then be imported into Studio5000.   This will allow to stick to your predefined standard.  You would just have that secondary step of moving back into the Rockwell software before downloading to the PLC.

Here is a link to Rockwell's Official guide:
http://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/rm/1756-rm084_-en-p.pdf

I hope that answers what you were asking.